# Assign id to div dynamically created from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to assign dynamic `id` attributes to the div(s) which are being appended through JavaScript. For example:

```
function x() {
    for (current_list = 0; current_list < data.length; current_list++) {
        $("#current").append(
            "<div class="card">" +
            "<a href="" + data[current_list].url + "">" + data[current_list].name + "</a>" +
            "</div>");
    }
}
```

Two cards will be appended, so I want to assign them an `id` which can increase if there are more numbers of arrays present in the JSON.

Comment: You mean class `card1, card2, card3, ...`?

Comment: Be careful with your quotes as your syntax is currently broken. I'd also question why you need the `id` attributes at all. Using DOM traversal is often a simpler technique to do what you require.

Comment: yes, cards will increase with time.

Answer (score 1):

you probably looking for this.

```
function x() {
  var container=$("#current");
  for(var i=1;i<10;i++)
  {
    var id="card"+i;
    var divHtml="<div class='"+id+"'>" +
      "<a href=""+data[current_list].url+"">"+data[current_list].name+"</a>" +
    "</div>"
    container.append(divHtml);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rory said, here a solution using DOM traversal.
You would have to call this after appending your "cards".

```
$(".card").each(function(value, index){
   $(value).attr("id", "card" + index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you call x() function one time you can use

```
function x() {
  for (current_list = 0; current_list < data.length; current_list++) {
    $("#current").append('<div id="card-'+current_list+'" class="card"><a href="' + data[current_list].url + '">' + data[current_list].name + '</a></div>');
  }
}
```

and if you call it many time you can use this function after every call

```
$(".card").each(function(value, index){
  $(value).attr("id", "card-" + index);
});
```